# Broadcasting custom intent from one service to another

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-broadcast, watch-face-api

I have two services. I need to broadcast custom intent with data from one service. and in second service I need to receive it. I have tried following:

In first service:

```
  public String ACTION_CHANGE_TIME_FORMAT = "com.example.agile.mywatchface.changetimeformat";

Intent timeFormatIntent = new Intent();
                    timeFormatIntent.putExtra("format", 12);
                    timeFormatIntent.setAction(ACTION_CHANGE_TIME_FORMAT);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(timeFormatIntent);
```

In Second Service:

```
  public String ACTION_CHANGE_TIME_FORMAT = "com.example.agile.mywatchface.changetimeformat";

    public class TimeFormatReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(MyPreferences.LOGCAT_TAG, "Time format Broadcast received: ");
            format = intent.getExtras().getInt("format", 0);
            updateTime();
        }
    }
```

and I have registered and unregistered receivers properly in second service:

```
   IntentFilter timeFormatIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    timeFormatIntentFilter.addAction(ACTION_CHANGE_TIME_FORMAT);
    MyWatchfaceService.this.registerReceiver(timeFormatReceiver, timeFormatIntentFilter);
```

Is there anything wrong here? I can't get data(`format`).

Edit: `onRecieve()` is not calling.

Answer (score 0):

In Second Service:
Change `format = intent.getExtras().getInt("format", 0);` to `format = intent.getIntExtra("format", 0);`

The `intent.getExtras()` will return the `Bundle` which put by `Intent.putExtras(Bundle bundle)`, but you didn't do it.

Comment: my onReceive()  is not calling

Comment: When do you regist/unregist your receiver?

Answer (score 0):

1_ Check that your onReceive() method is called. If not, your Receiver still does not registered.

2_ if (1) is OK, try `int format = intent.getIntExtra("format", 0);`

P/S: I dont know where do you use the "format" variable, consider use it as local variable and pass it like a parameter.

```
int format = intent.getIntExtra("format", 0);
updateTime(format)
```

Comment: Check these conditions:
1) Your receiver is declared in manifest file?
2) The code registerReceiver() is called, I mean your second service is started and register your BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: I registered programmatically. Do i need explicitely register in reciever?

Comment: Sorry, you don't need declare it in manifest in this case. But when and where the code register is called? Is the second service started or bound?